# Add hours to Date JASPERsoft Studio/ Add hours to mongodb query date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, jasper-reports

Im trying to add 8 hours to the date I am getting from jasperstudio. The class type of the date im using is STRING. Does anyone know how to add hours from a date that is in string.

```
DATEFORMAT(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse($P{fromdate}) ,"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm")
```

This is what I used in a text field but I dont know how to add hours. The date came from a MongoDB database that is -8hrs

Would it be best if I add it in my mongodb Query? How to add hours in ISO dateformat?

or make the calculation in jasperstudio?

Thank you!

Comment: In MongoDB 5.0 function [$dateAdd](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/) has been added.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach it to modify your MongoDB query to give what you want.

This is not a responsability for jasper since data needs to be transformed from MongoDB in your case.

Can you post your MongoDB Query (MQL)?

You can check this link to use $add aggregation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/